# How can I declare a C array containing C arrays?

Tags: c, arrays

Given the short notation to declare arrays, how do I specify the type of myArray to be arrays?

```
[] myArray = {   //here [] should be array type
            {"obj1, "obj2"},        
            {"obj1, "obj2"}
}
```

Comment: What is "the short notation to declare arrays"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want a two-dimensional array of character strings:

```
const char *myArray[][2] = {
        {"obj1", "obj2"},        
        {"obj1", "obj2"}
        /* any other elements */
};
```

Comment: array type has incomplete element type, which means that `size` is needed here `const char *myArray[2][SIZE]`.